# Long text is outside of the div

Tags: html, css

I've trying to make a test website, but there is a problem.

Here's is a picture, which show you, what's the problem: [image: http://kepfeltoltes.hu/view/140409/734683293asd_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg]

The years (2010,2011,2012) are folders, and the '2013' folder contain some pictures. There's a php function, which I can read the folders and the picture names.

The DOM structure:

Főoldal
                    Elérhetőség
                    Önkéntes munka
                    Képtár

                
                
                    Főoldal

```
        <div id="bottom">
        bhvdksakd
        </div>
```

The CSS:

```
#main{
    max-width:22cm;
    min-width:16cm;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin:0px auto 20px auto;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
}
#left{
    display:block;
    width:20%;
    min-height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    border-right:1px solid rgba(192,192,192,0.5);
}
#right{
    display:block;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    width:80%;
    text-align:justify;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:20%;
    padding:20px;
}
#bottom{
    max-width:22cm;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

Is there any css method or anything, that the contain isn't outside of the "right" div?

Thanks!

ps: Sorry for my sentences, but I'm from Hungary :/

Comment: Please share the entire HTML for reproducing the problem, or share a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: you abused the use of position:absolute; that why you container doesn't grow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto;` to your CSS for the div with overflowing content.

This property will automatically add a scroll bar only on necessary axes to help contain content within the boundaries of the div. So if you have too much vertical content, you get a vertical (y) scrollbar. If you have too much horizontal content, you get a horizontal (x) scrollbar.

Comment: yes, I tryed it, but the result won't be so nice, because, the "scrolling line" will be in the div. But I would like to, that, the height of the website will be bigger :/

Comment: @user3290356 I don't quite understand your second sentence. If you want the div itself to just be taller, you can try setting `height:auto;` or setting a specific height if the amount of content isn't dynamic.

Comment: thanks, the tip, but it doesn't work. And yes, I want to the right div will dynamic, if the text is longer, the div will be taller, but the minimum height will be 100%.

Comment: @user3290356 If you have `min-height: 100%;` set, then it will take at least 100% height of its parent div, **but** if the height of the parent div is not set explicitly then this using a percentage won't work. Also using a value of 100% for `min-height` is kind of unnecessary; just use `height: 100%;` or use `min-height: 50%` or something.

In order for us to help you, we need to see your HTML

Comment: what about the child in absolute position ? , this is where it goes wrong :)

Comment: I've successfully solved the problem, with Jquery (when I clicked a link the main div's height will uqual to the right div's height) Thank you, everybody :)