# Text is outside of the image, when decreasing the browser width

Tags: html, image, css

If I paste text into an image, then this looks fine in this example. But if I reduce the browser width, then the text slips out of the picture.

In addition, unsightly line breaks are added.

How can I prevent these two things?

There should be a solution without scrollbar.

[Long text is outside of the div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964761/long-text-is-outside-of-the-div)

Here is an example:  https://jsfiddle.net/1228sbg7/3/

```css
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 33%;
   height: auto;
}

h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}

h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}

h2 span.spacer {
   padding:0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">

      <img src="https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=21049048" alt="" />
      
      <h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet:<span class='spacer'></span><br /><span class='spacer'></span>consetetur sadipscing elitr</span></h2>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting **overflow: hidden;** in the your CSS definition for the < h2 > element.

```
h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also,  replace your .image CSS class definition with the following:

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Additional edits based on your comments:  It looks like you really want padding around the darkened area with the text.  I've altered your HTML further, wrapping the `<h2>` tags around a div.  Instead of applying the darker background in the `<h2>` tag,  we're applying the style on the `<div>` wrapping the `<h2>` elements.

Then, use min-width  to set minimum width of your wrapper, to ensure text does not wrap beyond the height of your image.

```css
body {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;

}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
}


.darkerDiv {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0;
    text-align:left;
    min-width:170px !important;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.darkerDiv h2 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.darkerDiv h2 span {
    color: white;
    font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.darkerDiv h2 span.spacer {
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet2.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/301599/pexels-photo-301599.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=250&w=400" alt="" />
        <div class="darkerDiv">    
             <h2><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet: <br />
             consetetur sadipscing elitr</span></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help either

Comment: I had to remove that width:50%; from  the .image class to prevent the line wraps.

Comment: But what can I do, that the text behave, like I want and there is padding on the right hand side of the text?

Comment: I'm not really sure of what you meant...how do you want the text to behave?   Should it wrap at all?

Comment: There are a few problems with this solution: The image don't scale, and the picture width is not 33%.  And if you still decrease the browser width, then the text is outside of the picture ( https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=32864200 ). And of the end and beginning of the line is no padding as you can see here: https://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=17237414  Thanks anyway for your help